# Service account for SQL Server services

Tags: sql-server

I was reading a lot of recommendations from MS and famous SQL bloggers that we need to use service account in order to run SQL Server services but didn't get any clarification. Can you please advice what are my risks if I leave start-up account as default local one? For me it is seems like additional overheads changing password on our entire servers once a year.

Thanks in advance,
Aibek Gubashov

Comment: As you said, there are a lot of articles that explains this. Why would you expect a sort answer in SO to do a better job ? A local account doesn't have more *risks* it has more *restrictions*, eg it can't access network resources like file shares

Comment: are you in Domain? and what version of MS SQL you are using? Since 2012 they are using different creditential.